# thymeleaf eq with spring variables bug?

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I'm trying to run the following th:if:

> th:if="${camelContext.getRouteStatus( route.id )} &eq; 'Hey'

but I get this error:

> org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as expression: "${camelContext.getRouteStatus( route.id )} &neq; 'Hey' " (camel:92)

However, if I try

> th:if="${camelContext.getRouteStatus( route.id )} > 41 "

I get a different error, but now indicating that it's able to parse the expression, its just that it cannot compare Strings and numbers:

> Cannot execute GREATER THAN from Expression "${camelContext.getRouteStatus( route.id )} > 41". Left is "Started", right is "41" (camel:92)

That's fine, I just wanted to check if I was writing the syntax correctly, and I don't want to compare numbers anyways, I want to compare the RouteStatus string.

Anyways, maybe someone can help me with this problem? Basically I want to do a if-else on the contents of a string, but I can't get this to work..

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
th:if="${camelContext.getRouteStatus( route.id )} == 'Hey'"
```

Maybe it will work like this?

The example on the thymeleaf shows something similar:
Values in expressions can be compared with the >, <, >= and <= symbols, as usual, and also the == and != operators can be used to check equality (or the lack of it). Note that XML establishes that the < and > symbols should not be used in attribute values, and so they should be substituted by < and >.

```
    th:if="${prodStat.count} gt; 1"
th:text="'Execution mode is ' + ( (${execMode} == 'dev')? 'Development' : 'Production')"
```

Even though textual aliases exist for some of these operators: gt (>), lt (<), ge (>=), le (<=), not (!). Also eq (==), neq/ne (!=), it is sometimes still better to stick with the old fashion operators.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your expression is malformed, but maybe this a copy paste issue.

Could you try: `th:if="${camelContext.getRouteStatus( route.id ) eq 'Hey'}` ?

Comment: I think it then tries to interpret the whole thing as a spring expression:
`org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "camelContext.getRouteStatus( route.id ) eq 'Hey' " (camel:92)`

I also tried
`${${camelContext.getRouteStatus( route.id )} eq 'Hey'}`
but I get the same error as with your suggestion.

Comment: Which version of thymeleaf are you using ?